# У дочерних объектов не работает space-around, не появляются отступы в общем контейнере с display:flex

Tags: html, css

У меня в коде не работает space around у header-line

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Baumans', cursive;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px 70px;
}

.header {
  background-image: url(./image/SCP_Foundation_Logo_v3.png);
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.textlogo {
  color: #CF2323;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.textlogo:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header-line {
  padding-top: 34px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.mainmenuitem {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.mainmenuitem:hover {
  color: #ce0000;
}

.line1 {
  padding-right: 20px;
  height: 50px;
}

.gma {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.gma:hover {
  color: #ce0000;
}

.gmail-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
}

.gmail-holder {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.gmail-item {
  margin: 0px 10px;
  color: white;
}

#gi1 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

#gi2 {
  padding-left: 3vh;
}

#gi3 {
  padding-left: 3vh;
}

.button {
  font-size: 44px;
  background-color: #00E1E1;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 50px;
  border-radius: 38px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #00a0a0;
}

.header-title {
  color: #AED21A;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baumans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Донат Delta</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header-line">
        <div class="header-logo">
          <a href="-" class="textlogo"><img src="./image/logo.png" width="102px" height="102px" alt="">Delta MediumRp</a>
        </div>

        <div class="mainmenu">
          <a class="mainmenuitem" href="-">Главная</a>
          <a class="mainmenuitem" href="-">Привелегии</a>
          <a class="mainmenuitem" href="-">О нас</a>
        </div>
        <div class="line1">
          <img src="./image/line1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="gmail">
          <div class="gmail-holder">
            <div id="gi1" class="gmail-item">Есть вопросы?</div>
            <div id="gi2" class="gmail-item">Напишите на почту!</div>
            <div class="gmai"><a id="gi3" class="gma" href='@'>akkbezbanov@gmail.com</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
          <a class="button" href="#">Донат</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="header-down">

        <div class="header-title">
          Донат Delta MediumRp
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

то-есть должно получиться так[image: элементы]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что родительский `.container` имеет `display: flex`, а значит его общая ширина будет складываться из размеров дочерних элементов, лишних отступов нету. Можно задать для `.header-line` `flex-grow: 1`, чтобы занимал всю всю доступную ширину и тогда возможно появляться и отступы. Или вручную задать `margin` слева и справа. (код смотреть на полном разрешении)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Baumans', cursive;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px 70px;
}

.header {
  background-image: url(./image/SCP_Foundation_Logo_v3.png);
  background: #000;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.textlogo {
  color: #CF2323;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.textlogo:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header-line {
  padding-top: 34px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-grow: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.mainmenuitem {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.mainmenuitem:hover {
  color: #ce0000;
}

.line1 {
  padding-right: 20px;
  height: 50px;
}

.gma {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.gma:hover {
  color: #ce0000;
}

.gmail-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
}

.gmail-holder {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.gmail-item {
  margin: 0px 10px;
  color: white;
}

#gi1 {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#gi2 {
  padding-left: 3vh;
}

#gi3 {
  padding-left: 3vh;
}

.button {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #00E1E1;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 50px;
  border-radius: 38px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #00a0a0;
}

.header-title {
  color: #AED21A;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baumans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Донат Delta</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header-line">
        <div class="header-logo">
          <a href="-" class="textlogo"><img src="./image/logo.png" width="102px" height="102px" alt="">Delta MediumRp</a>
        </div>

        <div class="mainmenu">
          <a class="mainmenuitem" href="-">Главная</a>
          <a class="mainmenuitem" href="-">Привелегии</a>
          <a class="mainmenuitem" href="-">О нас</a>
        </div>
        <div class="line1">
          <img src="./image/line1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="gmail">
          <div class="gmail-holder">
            <div id="gi1" class="gmail-item">Есть вопросы?</div>
            <div id="gi2" class="gmail-item">Напишите на почту!</div>
            <div class="gmai"><a id="gi3" class="gma" href='@'>akkbezbanov@gmail.com</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
          <a class="button" href="#">Донат</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="header-down">

        <div class="header-title">
          Донат Delta MediumRp
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```